# issue with subprocess.call

Tags: python-2.7, subprocess, youtube-dl

Python 2.7.3 with ubuntu:

Trying to run a program, (youtube-dl in this example) with `subprocess.call` with some arguments, I encounter the following issue. consider the following script:

**try.py:**

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from subprocess import call

url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8SbUC-UaAxE"
myArray = ['./youtube-dl {}'.format(url),'-x','--audio-format mp3']
#print the array before executing:
for item in myArray:
    print item,
#execute:
call(myArray)
```

This script prints outputs:

```
oris@oris:~/Desktop/YouTube/backend$ ./try.py 
./youtube-dl https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8SbUC-UaAxE -x --audio-format mp3
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./try.py", line 16, in <module>
call(myArray)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 493, in call
return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1259, in _execute_child
raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Strangly, On the first line of the output I see the script does output `./youtube-dl https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8SbUC-UaAxE -x --audio-format mp3` 
This command runs perfectly from bash directly, but produces an OSError from python. I also thought maybe to try and supply the `url` as an argument like this:

```
myArray = ['./youtube-dl', url,'-x','--audio-format mp3']
```

but than `youtube-dl` has an error of incorrect usage:

```
 oris@oris:~/Desktop/YouTube/backend$ ./try.py 
 Usage: youtube-dl [options] url [url...]

 youtube-dl: error: no such option: --audio-format mp3
 ./youtube-dl https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8SbUC-UaAxE -x --audio-format mp3
```

I've read youtube-dl source to see how it [handles the supplied arguments](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/) with [optparse](http://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html). I don't see the url as an argument there, so I'm guessing i'm passing the arguments to `subprocess.call` incorrectly. 
**Side note:** another thing I find odd is the fact the print here takes effect after the subprocess call, as opposed to their order on my script. Is something happening here asynchronously? 
What am I missing here? Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`--audio-format` and `mp3` should be passed as separated arguments:

```
myArray = ['./youtube-dl', url, '-x', '--audio-format', 'mp3']
```

Comment: @user1555863, Did you try it with `call(..., shell=True)`?

Comment: Thank you. That simple huh? This actually works without `shell=True`. I wonder about these nuances. What's happening here?

Comment: @user1555863, If you pass `[....., '--audio-format mp3']`, `youtube-dl` consider `--audio-format mp3` as a option (not only `--audio-format`). (Not only for youtube-dl, but any program that accept option)

Comment: @user1555863, Replace `youtube-dl` with your own program that print `sys.argv`, then you'll get it.

Comment: great stuff! appreciate your help.